# How can i install python exe using wine in docker without opening the installation window

Tags: python, docker, wine

I'm writing a dockerfile that executes python-3.8.0.exe using wine on ubuntu 18.04.

After installing everything that's needed to run wine I run

```
RUN set -x \
    && winetricks win10
    && wget -nv https://www.python.org/ftp/python/$PYTHON_VERSION/python-$PYTHON_VERSION.exe
RUN set -x \
    && wine python-$PYTHON_VERSION.exe
```

I'm also using a virtual machine to test different commands. The command itself works but leads to the installer window being opened. How can i skip that part and directly install the desired python version?

Comment: Not really a solution to your problem, but you may be better using the python version provided by the package manager of the underlying distribution, instead of using the windows version of python in a presumably linux container. This however only applies, if it's not a hard requirement.

Comment: Could you install Python directly in the VM?  An emulator inside a container inside a VM seems like a lot of layers.